# Displaying pdf in laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5

I'm creating a site where an author uploads a pdf file. The way I've created my site is there is a page where story titles is shown, if a person clicks on the title it uses the story slug to go to the story, but I want a pdf to be displayed when the the title is clicke d. I'm not sure where to start. I have tried barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, but it doesn't have a "partial" section to display a pdf. It only allows for the pdf to be viewed as a whole page. I hope I made sense.

Something similar to this [Google Books](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=iOK9CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT245&lpg=PT245&dq=online%20pdf%20stories&source=bl&ots=_Y8e0rUwkK&sig=FuB-Tbt3Y16oTW10_ofTcZoYIr8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=online%20pdf%20stories&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way :

```
$filename = 'test.pdf';
$path = storage_path($filename);

return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
]);
```

Try this html object tag :

```
<div>
    <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
        alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: That create a whole page. I need a section of my page to be pdf and another section that is my site for comments

Comment: I still get the whole page